# How to create form in view from different model in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Iam new to yii. I am developing customer project app. I have a view wherein iam displaying the data from both the models, customer and projects.

How do i create a form to add new projects?
[my project is here](http://tinyurl.com/od7qy64)

To display project data in customer view, iam using

```
$query=Projects::find()
    ->where(['projects_clients_id'=> $model->customer_id]);    

       $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,        
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can render several model and/or dataProvider  in a view  *(properly constructed)*

eg:

```
    return $this->render('viewTestMulti', [
        'modelOne'                 =>$modelOne,
        'dataProviderTwo'                => $providerTwo,
        'dataProviderThree'      => $providerThree,
        'modeFour'                    => $modelFour,
    ]);
```

And then you can use  a view with several gridView related to proper dataProvider and several forms everyone with a proper action 
so when you press the specified submit you invoke the proper controller action

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>


<?php $formOne = ActiveForm::begin(); 
      $formOne->action=  yii\helpers\Url::to('ControllerOne\create');
 ?>

<?= $formOne->field($modelOne, 'name') ?>

<?= $formOne->field($modelOne, 'email') ?>

<div class="form-group">
   <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>



<?php $formFour = ActiveForm::begin(); 
   $formFour->action= yii\helpers\Url::to('ControllerFour\create');
?>

<?= $formFour->field($modelFour, 'name_four') ?>

<?= $formFour->field($modelFour, 'email_four') ?>

<div class="form-group">
   <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I hope this could be useful

Comment: Yes, Actually I was looking something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the documentation about [ActiveForms](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html) and I recommend, if you are new in Yii2 to use [The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html), [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html) the Forms Section

This is a basic form:

```
<?php
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You should create another `modelForm` for any form what you want. The optimal way is one model for each table or model. This answer your question?

Comment: Sageth..I agree..But I am get confused to use the form from a different model. If I implement the above form, it will just taken the data from Customers table. I need the projects table

Comment: Ok. As i have shown in  my demo, i have a page with customers along with their projects. I want to add a new project from the same page.. I have no problems displaying data from projects models. But how to create a form to add new project?How do I do it?

Comment: You need, a Project `model` you can created with `Gii` tool, a `controller` wich use this model to store data, a `view` with the form, and a ProjectForm `model` to validate the data from the form and used to send it to another action of the controller. I dont wanna be a stickler but The definitive guide explains how MVC works better than me :D